# Using type checking on setter decorated functions with Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use type hinting or type checking on class variables with decorators:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 10

    @property
    def value(self) -> int:
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value: int):
        self._value = value

    def set_another_value(self, value: int):
        print(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test()
    test.value = "Test"
    test.set_another_value("Test")
```

Neither the code checker in Pycharm nor Pylint wont give me a warning when doing
`test.value = "Test"`

Only mypy seems to recognize it. Did I miss something when using `@value.setter` ?

[pycharm code checker output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH3eA.png)